# Cycling of values in for loops - Maple

Tags: loops, for-loop, maple

I am trying to write code to give the output 3,-3,3 and then end the procedure.  Ideally I am trying to get something where if A takes a value it has already had in a previous loop this is recognized and this fact is printed.
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
optimality:=proc()

global A,B
local i;
A:=3
for i from 1 to 10 do

A*(-1):=B;
A:=B;
print(A);
end do:
end proc:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the output `3, -3, 3`, then you can just use `seq`

```
seq(3*(-1)^(i-1),i = 1..10);
```

or if it *has* to print the values,

```
print(seq(3*(-1)^(i-1),i = 1..10));
```

but be aware that when printing, you cannot assign them to a variable.

The above can be generalized to whatever amount you require by changing the index of `i = 1..N`.

---

Now, if your objective is to understand and work with procedures, the above does not really help much.

Notice that in your `do`-loop, it sets `A:=B` and so `B` is redundant; simply replace the two-line code

```
A*(-1):=B;
A:=B;
```

with

```
A:=A*(-1);
```

Also be aware that you cannot perform operations on the left-hand-side of a variable assignment - at minimum the `*(-1)` should be on the right-hand-side.

Your code could then look something like

```
optimality:=proc()
    global A;
    local i;
A:=3;
for i from 1 to 10 do
    A:=A*(-1);
    print(A);
end do:
end proc:
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize as you see fit...

```
restart;

randomize():

cycl := proc( A, input, f, {bail::truefalse:=true} )
  local i,B,T;
  B:=input;
  A[B]:=1;
  T[1]:=B;
  for i from 2 to 10 do
    B:=f(B);
    if assigned(A[B]) then
      printf("revisited value found: %a\n",[seq(j=T[j],j=A[B]..i-1),i=B]);
      if bail then
        #return seq(j=T[j],j=A[B]..i-1),i=B;
        return seq(T[j],j=A[B]..i-1),B;
      else
        A[B]:=i;
        T[i]:=B;
        # Or perhaps you just wanted to break the loop here.
      end if;
    else
      A[B]:=i;
      T[i]:=B;
    end if;
  end do;
  convert(T,list); # all the values generated
end proc:

A := 'A':
cycl( A, 3, (x->-x) );

  revisited value found: [1 = 3, 2 = -3, 3 = 3]

                              3, -3, 3

eval( A ); # last position for each distinct value

                       TABLE([-3 = 2, 3 = 1])

A := 'A':
cycl( A, 3, (x->-x), bail=false );

  revisited value found: [1 = 3, 2 = -3, 3 = 3]
  revisited value found: [2 = -3, 3 = 3, 4 = -3]
  revisited value found: [3 = 3, 4 = -3, 5 = 3]
  revisited value found: [4 = -3, 5 = 3, 6 = -3]
  revisited value found: [5 = 3, 6 = -3, 7 = 3]
  revisited value found: [6 = -3, 7 = 3, 8 = -3]
  revisited value found: [7 = 3, 8 = -3, 9 = 3]
  revisited value found: [8 = -3, 9 = 3, 10 = -3]

                 [3, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3]

eval(A); # last position for each distinct value

                       TABLE([-3 = 10, 3 = 9])

A := 'A':
cycl( A, 3, rand(7) );

  revisited value found: [2 = 5, 3 = 4, 4 = 1, 5 = 2, 6 = 5]

                            5, 4, 1, 2, 5

eval( A ); # last position for each distinct value

             TABLE([1 = 4, 2 = 5, 3 = 1, 4 = 3, 5 = 2])

A := 'A':
cycl( A, 3, rand(7), bail=false );

  revisited value found: [1 = 3, 2 = 3]
  revisited value found: [4 = 0, 5 = 0]
  revisited value found: [2 = 3, 3 = 5, 4 = 0, 5 = 0, 6 = 2, 7 = 6, 8 = 3]
  revisited value found: [6 = 2, 7 = 6, 8 = 3, 9 = 2]
  revisited value found: [9 = 2, 10 = 2]

                   [3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2]

  eval( A ); # last position for each distinct value

             TABLE([0 = 5, 2 = 10, 3 = 8, 5 = 3, 6 = 7])
```